# Ajax not working properly. PHP cannot insert data in SQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I am using Jquery array to fetch variables on dynamic input forms. I could group and output the arrays into the console.log, but no data could be inserted within the multiple table database itself.

here's the Jquery code with ajax and console.log

```
    $("button[name='submit_addPackresCategories']").click(function(){
        var packres_categories_name;
        $("input[id='packres_categories_name']").each(function(){
            packres_categories_name = this.value;
        });
        console.log(packres_categories_name);

        var packres_categories_description;
        $("textarea[id='packres_categories_description']").each(function(){
            packres_categories_description = this.value;
        });
        console.log(packres_categories_description);

        var packres_categories_paxhead_day = {};
        $("input[id^='packres_categories_paxhead_day']").each(function(){
            packres_categories_paxhead_day[this.id] = this.value;
        });
        console.log(packres_categories_paxhead_day);

        var packres_categories_paxhead_price = {};
        $("input[id^='packres_categories_paxhead_price']").each(function(){
            packres_categories_paxhead_price[this.id] = this.value;
        });
        console.log(packres_categories_paxhead_price);

        var packres_categories_paxgroup_size = {};
        $("input[id^='packres_categories_paxgroup_size']").each(function(){
            packres_categories_paxgroup_size[this.id] = this.value;
        });
        console.log(packres_categories_paxgroup_size);

        var packres_categories_paxgroup_consumable = {};
        $("input[id^='packres_categories_paxgroup_consumable']").each(function(){
            packres_categories_paxgroup_consumable[this.id] = this.value;
        });
        console.log(packres_categories_paxgroup_consumable);

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/addPackresCategories.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                packres_categories_name: packres_categories_name,
                packres_categories_description: packres_categories_description,
                packres_categories_paxhead_day: packres_categories_paxhead_day,
                packres_categories_paxhead_price: packres_categories_paxhead_price,
                packres_categories_paxgroup_size: packres_categories_paxgroup_size,
                packres_categories_paxgroup_consumable: packres_categories_paxgroup_consumable
            }
        })
        .done(function(response){
            if (JSON.parse(response)) {
                alert("Successfully Added New Package!");
            }
            else {
                alert("Failed!");
            }
        });
    });
```

here's the url for the ajax

```
<?php
    include_once("../db.php");
    include "admin_session.php";

    $packres_categories_name = $_POST["packres_categories_name"];
    $packres_categories_description = $_POST["packres_categories_description"];
    $packres_categories_paxhead = array_combine($_POST["packres_categories_paxhead_day"], $_POST["packres_categories_paxhead_price"]);
    $packres_categories_paxgroup = array_combine($_POST["packres_categories_paxgroup_size"], $_POST["packres_categories_paxgroup_consumable"])

    $sql_insertPackresNameDesc_packresCategories = "INSERT INTO packres_categories(packres_categories_name, packres_categories_description) VALUES('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $packres_categories_name) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $packres_categories_description) . "')";
    $query_sql_insertPackresNameDesc_packresCategories = $conn->query($sql_insertPackresNameDesc_packresCategories);
    $affectedRows_query_sql_insertPackresNameDesc_packresCategories = mysqli_affected_rows($conn); //will be used to verify if inserted properly on database later

    $packres_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);//will be used later

    foreach ($packres_categories_paxhead as $key => $value) {
        $sql_insertPackresCategoriesPaxhead_packresCategoriesPaxHead = "INSERT INTO packres_categories_paxhead(packres_id, packres_categories_paxhead_day, packres_categories_paxhead_day) VALUES('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $packres_id) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $key) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value) . "')";
        $query_sql_insertPackresCategoriesPaxhead_packresCategoriesPaxHead = $conn->query($insertPackresCategoriesPaxhead_packresCategoriesPaxHead);
        $affectedRows_query_sql_insertPackresCategoriesPaxhead_packresCategoriesPaxHead += mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
    }

    foreach ($packres_categories_paxgroup as $key => $value) {
        $sql_insertPackresCategoriesPaxGroup_packresCategoriesPaxgroup = "INSERT INTO packres_categories_paxgroup(packres_id, packres_categories_paxgroup_size, packres_categories_paxgroup_consumable) VALUES('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $packres_id) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $key) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value) . "')";
        $query_sql_insertPackresCategoriesPaxGroup_packresCategoriesPaxgroup = $conn->query($sql_insertPackresCategoriesPaxGroup_packresCategoriesPaxgroup);
        $affectedRows_query_sql_insertPackresCategoriesPaxGroup_packresCategoriesPaxgroup += mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
    }

    $conn->close();

    if (($affectedRows_query_sql_insertPackresNameDesc_packresCategories != 0) && ($affectedRows_query_sql_insertPackresCategoriesPaxhead_packresCategoriesPaxHead != 0) && ($$affectedRows_query_sql_insertPackresCategoriesPaxGroup_packresCategoriesPaxgroup != 0)) {
        echo json_encode(true);
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode(false);
    }
?>
```

arrays of data should be inserted properly into the database, but no data were entering the database.

error line being thrown at console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (master.js:70)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: will look into that. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

json_encode()- returns the JSON representation of a value.
And you are returning boolean